# Automatic Startup of Oracle 11gR2 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos, startup, oracle-database

I've setup a handful of CentOS 5.6 servers with Oracle 11gR2 and not run into this particular problem, but I have hit a wall with CentOS 6.3 and auto-starting Oracle. Not sure if this is related to the newer release of CentOS or me having a PEBKAC moment, but I need a hand.

I've got a working install of Oracle 11gR2 on CentOS 6.3. It runs and is functional. Now I just want it to start with the server. To that end, I've done the following things I usually do:

Created /etc/init.d/oracle:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# oracle Init file for starting and stopping
# Oracle Database. Script is valid for 10g and 11g versions.
# chkconfig: 35 80 30
# description: Oracle Database startup script

# Source function library.

. /etc/init.d/functions

ORACLE_OWNER="oracle"
ORACLE_HOME="/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1"

case "$1" in
        start)
                su - $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart $ORACLE_HOME"
                ;;
        stop)
                su - $ORACLE_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbshut $ORACLE_HOME"
                ;;
        *)
                echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
esac
```

Than ran the following two commands:

```
  chmod 750 /etc/init.d/oracle
  chkconfig --add oracle --level 0356
```

When I try a `service oracle start`, (as root) however, I get this error:

```
env: /etc/init.d/oracle: No such file or directory
```

Not sure how to figure out what file we're looking for.

If I run that script's actual start command with the variables expanded the database starts with no errors.

```
su - oracle -c "/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/dbstart /opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1"
```

So... what am I missing here? Some casual web searching makes me feel like this approach should still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bah. Figured it out right after posting it...

The whole issue was that I had created the "oracle" file on a PC and uploaded it. So it had the wrong line-endings. Rebuilt the file and everything works fine.